# Passing methods as parameter vs calling methods directly

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I have seen methods passed as parameters in some examples. If I can call one method from another method, why should I pass method as a parameter? What is the purpose behind this design?

1. Calling one method from another
2. Passing method as parameter using delegate or `Action`

Answer (score 2):

Passing in a method as a parameter can be used to prevent dependencies and coupling. Let's take a look at how this can be used for the Strategy pattern:

Let's say we have a method `PrintReport`, which prints a given list of items, which might be sorted by Name or by Type, based on a parameter. This is the naive approach:

```
public void PrintReport (List<Item> data, SortOrder sortBy)
{
    List<Item> sortedItems;
    switch (sortBy)
    {
        case SortOrder.Name: sortedItems = SortByName(data); break;
        case SortOrder.Type: sortedItems = SortByType(data); break;
    }

    Print(sortedItems);
}
```

It's simple but it works. But what happens when we want to add a new sort order? We need to update the SortOrder enum, go into `PrintReport` and add a new `case` and call the new `SortByWhatever` method.

But if we passed in a method as a parameter, our `PrintReport` can be simpler and not care about the sort implementation:

```
public void PrintReport (List<Item> data, Func<List<Item>, List<Item>> sorter)
{
    List<Item> sortedItems = sorter(data);
    Print(sortedItems);
}
```

Now the sorting function can be defined anyway, possibly even in a different assembly that `PrintReport` isn't even aware of. It can be a lambda function or an anonymous method defined ad-hoc. But in all cases, our method will receive the delegate, use it to sort, and then print the report.

Here's a usage example. At first it looks like we merely moved the switch/case outside of the function, which is important enough since it allows different callers to have different logic. But watch for the third case.

```
public void HandleData()
{
    switch (ReportItemOrder)
    {
        case SortOrder.Name: PrintReport(data, SortByName); break;
        case SortOrder.Type: PrintReport(data, SortByType); break;
        case SortOrder.Whatever: 
        Func<List<Item>, List<Item>> customSort = (items) => /* do something */;
        PrintReport(data, customSort);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Delegates are commonly used to decouple classes and interfaces from each other.

Here's a specific example. Suppose you had a UI class that was responsible for drawing a calendar, but you didn't want it to know exactly how to format the DateTime values into string.

You could define the class something like this:

```
public sealed class MyCalendarDrawer
{
    private readonly Func<DateTime, string> _dateFormatter;

    public MyCalendarDrawer(Func<DateTime, string> dateFormatter)
    {
        _dateFormatter = dateFormatter;
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        // Do some work that involves displaying dates...

        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

        string dateString = _dateFormatter(date);

        // Display dateString somehow.
    }
}
```

That way, `MyCalendarDrawer` doesn't need to know how to format the dates - it is told how to do it by being passed a delegate `Func<DateTime, string>` that it can call to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Treating functions as first class types has its advantages. It gives you functional programming possibilities.

Take the classic case of "Event Handling" for example, you will certainly send a function pointer to another function as a call-back on occurance of an event.

Similarly, here is another hypothetical example

```
private void CallMeBack(out int type, Func<int> action)
{
   type = action();
}
```

Now I can supply any function to this, like `CallMeBack(a, ()=>return 1);` and `CallMeBack(a, ()=>return 2);`

Comment: Instead of passing a function, you could pass an object implementing a given interface. There are no obvious advantages of passing functions around over passing objects around.

Comment: That's true. Delegates are a lot like interfaces, only for methods instead of classes. You can see it in the way .NET handles events (with delegates) vs.  how Java does it (with interfaces).
But the main difference is that it's easier to define ad-hoc methods (labmda, anonymous methods) vs ad-hoc interfaces)

Comment: Upcoming Lambdas in Java show that you don't really need delegates to have lambda expressions. It is not that I am against delegates but to be fair - we don't need them and still have the same power in the language. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about Delegates.
As example, delegates are useful to define a dynamic callback on a given method completion.

Pseudo-code example:

```
doSomething(); //your code
updateInterface(continueDoingSomething); //a generic method, passing a delegate

...

doAnythingElse();
updateInterface(continueDoingAnythingElse);
```

In this example, you could define a generic method "updateInterface" which, as a callback, calls a dynamic method passed in as a delegate.

If not using delegates, you would have to implement two (or more) different methods:

```
void updateInterfaceAndContinueDoingSomething(){}
void updateInterfaceAndContinueDoingAnythingElse(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Truth is, every single example where functions are passed to other functions can be expressed in term of objects implementing a given interface passed to functions.

In other words, there are no obvious reasons delegates are better than interfaces. Upcoming lambdas in Java are an example than you don't really need to be able to pass a function to another function to be able to have a concise syntax.

In yet another words, the ability to pass a function to another function is just a tool in your programmer's toolkit just as passing objectd to functions is. And while this is arguable which is better, one can have a language that doesn't support passing functions to functions at all - Java - and still be able to have the same expressiveness.

Comment: Isn't obvious that passing a delegate instead of an interface produces much lower coupling? Unless you invented a single-item interface just to do it - in which case, that's obviously a lot more work than just passing a delegate, especially if you just use a lambda.

Comment: Everyone knows the rationale behind delegates and that still doesn't make them a holy grail. Java has no delegates yet it will have lambda expressions via anonymous classes. Which means that anonymous classes offer almost the same level of low coupling.

Comment: Well, every time I see a Java class implementing multiple interfaces just to be able to subscribe to multiple events, I say my thanks to delegates. It may be only a stylistic difference, but that's enough for me.

Comment: What you talk about is a classis example of SRP/ISP violations existing in old Java interfaces. You should really take a look at their lambdas approach to see how they cope with their issues.

Comment: @Wiktor: Nobody said anything about it being a holy grail. But delegates definitely require less work *and* result in lower coupling than using interfaces.

Comment: If you have anonymous classes and some syntactic sugar in the language, there is really no difference. Lambdas in java look exactly like lambdas in C# just because the compile makes up a class instead of making up a method.

Comment: @Wiktor: If we were talking about Java, that might be relevant. But we're talking about C#, so it isn't.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: true. My reasoning behind this argument is that asking why you need to pass functions to functions is exactly like asking why you need to pass objects to functions. In other words, the answer is obvious but thr question is unintentionally spoiled with the technical detail of this specific language feature.

Comment: "Lambdas in java look exactly like lambdas in C# just because the compile makes up a class instead of making up a method."  -  How does work RE garbage creation?

Comment: What is a "garbage creation"?